# Playing Choir Piece on Piano

Tags: sheet-music

I have no formal music experience.  However, I like to learn piano songs I like through sheer memorization.  I can read sheet music, but the issue lies in two things; I do not have sheet music and the piece is written for choir.  The piece is Funeral Canticle, by John Tavener.  Here is a link:

.  Any tips on how to translate this into piano sheet music.  All the sheet music online is a physical copy and I don't have enough patience for that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options:

- Buy a physical copy. As you state, this will take some time. There might be a rehearsal part for piano, which you can use directly.
- Transcribe it yourself. This requires you to use your ears, and write down all the notes. This is quite time consuming, particularly if you've never done it before
- Learn it by ear. Similar to the previous option, but you don't write it down.

Honestly, the first will be the lowest effort option. Transcribing it will help you learn more, but it's going to take quite some time. You haven't specifically asked, but there isn't any software that will do this for you. There is certainly software that will help, but it will not be automatic.